# Is eWASM deployed on Ethereum?

Tags: ewasm

The project is there for 2 years, is still under development. I'm wondering if it's mature enough to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's deployed on the kovan testnet but not on the mainnet.

Comment: Thanks, @flygoing. Do you have any idea about how it works so far? Is there a timeline that it will be on mainnet?

Answer (score 1):

Take it for a spin and find out
https://github.com/paritytech/pwasm-tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1176&v=Adcn-L59LRs